# Using phpDoc, I get no errors, but no results either

Tags: php, phpdoc

With several files like this:

```
/**
 * Creates a new user account.
 * Collects posted form variables, escapes them, then passes them on to Storm.
 * @package User
 */

/**
 * Do includes.
 */
include_once('../Utilities.php');
include_once('../stormLibs/user.php');
```

...etc.

I then run phpDocumentor 2 from phpdoc.org. The results page shows no errors, but also no links to any files, packages or classes.

Any ideas?

Screenshot: [image: http://www.wildsky.com/phpdoc.jpg]

Comment: Just so you are aware, `/**
 * Do includes.
 */` is a useless comment, and therefor worse than *no comment at all*. Comments should describe *why* or *how* youu're doing something, not just restate *what* you're doing.

Comment: The point there is to have something show up in the generated docs. Any ideas on that?

Comment: @ChrisKohout: phpDoc comments are there to comments class, class members, methods and standalone functions. They do not document anything else. They need to be attached to one of the aforementioned tokens.

Answer (score 0):

That's odd that you don't even have the file itself show up listed as part of the User package.  I wonder if phpdoc2 is behaving such that a file only joins a package listing if it also contains some documentable element (class, function, constant).  If your file is only procedural code, there are probably no documentable elements in there, and so phpdoc2 thinks it has nothing to document.

As an experiment, if you file indeed does not have documentable elements in it, try adding an empty class declaration that includes a class-level docblock that puts it in the User package.  I'd be interested to see if that then makes both the class and the file appear in a User package listing.